# How to remove whitespace and \n from list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, list, strip

I have list of strings includes whitespace and \n like below.

```
['XXXXX',
  '\n\n                YYYYYYY\n              \n',
  'HHHHH',
  '\n\n                ZZZZZ\n              \n']
```

I have tried map, strip, and the others, but it did not work.
Could you help another way to fix this?

This list of strings from HTML table by web scraping, so there are a lot of whitespace and \n on it.

Comment: `l = [s.replace("\n", "") for s in l]`

Comment: You can use a comprehension: `data = [elm.strip() for elm in l]`

Comment: "I have tried map, strip, and the others, but it did not work" There's no such code in the question. If you want to know why your code does not work, please post the non-working code

Comment: Do you wan to remove *all* whitespace from the strings or just whitspace at the start and end of the strings?

Comment: Thank you all! Olvin one showed 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'' . Chiheb one showed AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Hi Rory, I would like to remove at the start and end of the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `map` and `strip`:

```
>>> L = ['XXXXX', '\n\n YYYYYYY\n \n', 'HHHHH', '\n\n ZZZZZ\n \n']
>>> list(map(str.strip, L))
['XXXXX', 'YYYYYYY', 'HHHHH', 'ZZZZZ']
```

Comment: Thank you TerryA! It showed TypeError: 'map' object is not callable. I am sorry why I can get this error message...

Comment: @montjeu Try converting the map object to a list, but it sounds like you're doing something like: `map(...)()`